# Any reason to use .php extension - not .html - if all PHP is handled by Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I named a file index.php while writing an app that uses PHP, Javascript and jQuery. In the end I realized there is no PHP code in the index.php file, so I changed the file extension to .html and, after some testing, it seems there are no problems.

Everything that touches the HTML in the index.html file is JavaScript. I'm reading fields from a form, writing to a MySQL database, and then reading the database and writing back to the HTML. The JavaScript is making Ajax requests to various PHP files.

If I use the filename index.html, am I likely I run into trouble if I move the files to a different Web server?

Comment: That depends on the web server you are moving to. Technically, you can have any extension you want and web server can route it to php and php can interpret that as its code. It's not possible to answer your question accurately - this is entirely dependent on web server configuration. If you don't know where you're moving or how it's configured, then it's the best to keep `.php` extension for files that deal with php code.

Comment: It all depends on how the server is configured to deliver requests. But likely not.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to give a file a `.php` file extension if it doesn't contain any PHP.

There are [various](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) different [reasons](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html) not to build your page so it only works if JavaScript is available though (which implies that the file should contain PHP, given that is your server side language of choice).

Comment: Nice resource, @Quentin - http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html - thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I prefer .php because if you want after time add some php code there you just cant.In .html cant be php code.

Comment: That's not really true. File extension doesn't guarantee anything. You can have .html parsed as php files easily. It's entirely dependent on server configuration.

Comment: What if you want to add some, say, Python code after some time‽ In other words: that reasoning is idiotic.